# How can I select a range of elements following a specific (.selected) element that has a different parent element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

As you can see, there are `.row` elements that are parent to `.cell` elements.

I have a **selected** element inside a `.row` element, I want to target:

> An element that is a child of the parent element that follows the parent containing .selected

Is this possible in CSS only?

Assume I want to select the second `.cell` of the parent next to the parent containing `.selected`

How do I turn the background color of the div containing the **number 13** green?

```css
.row .cell.selected {
  background-color: red
}
.row .cell.selected+.cell+.cell {
  background-color: red;
}
.row .cell.selected+.cell+.cell+.cell {
  background-color: red;
}
.row .cell.selected+.cell+.cell+.cell+.cell+.cell {
  background-color: red;
}
#month-view .row .cell.selected+.cell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.row {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="month-view">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"> <span>5</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell selected">
      <div class="day"><span>6</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>7</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>8</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>9</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>11</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell ">
      <div class="day"><span>12</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>13</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>14</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>15</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>16</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>17</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>18</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
/div>
```

Comment: "Is this possible in CSS only?" no, you'll need javascript to do that.

Comment: Actually there is no selector that allows you the target of that element, you can't do a step-back or know if contains ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question you want that the cell that gets a ".selected" class in the first row gets a styling in a cell in the same position in the second row.

That is not possible with CSS only, just using JS. CSS can't give you the index position of your ".selected" cell.

If you want a solution that is pure HTML and CSS I recommend you to add a second class like ".selected-column" to the next rows and style after this.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in CSS as you can't go backwards/up the DOM in CSS. But in case you can use JS or jQuery, here's a way. It's pretty easy and intuitive with jQuery using `$.parent()`, `$.next()`, and `:nth-child`.

```js
$('.selected').parent('.row').next('.row').find('.cell:nth-child(2)').addClass('green');
```

```css
.row .cell.selected {
  background-color: red
}

.row {
  padding: 50px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="month-view">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"> <span>5</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell selected">
      <div class="day"><span>6</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>7</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>8</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>9</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>10</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>11</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell ">
      <div class="day"><span>12</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>13</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>14</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>15</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>16</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>17</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="day"><span>18</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```